# How to intelligently & safely convert a Double to String?

Tags: c#, string, double, type-conversion

Trying not to repeat myself (to be DRY) here, help me out. =)

I have a **double** which represents a rating / 5.

The possible values are:

```
0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5.
```

I want to convert this to a **string** without the decimal place.

So the values would become:

```
"0", "05", "1", "15", "2", "25", "3", "35", "4", "45", "5".
```

Why am i doing this? Because i'm trying to dynamically create a link based on the value:

```
string link = "http://somewhere.com/images/rating_{0}.gif";
return string.Format(link, "15");
```

The possible values are handled/validated elsewhere, in other words i can be 100% sure the value will always be one of those i mentioned.

Any ideas? Some special format i can use in the `.ToString()` method? Or am i stuck with an un-DRY switch statement? Or can i cheekily do a `decimal.ToString().Replace(".","")`?

**EDIT:**

Whoah, thanks for all the answers guys! =)

Most answers are correct, so i'll leave this open for a day or so and pick the answer with the most votes.

Anyway, i ended up creating a simple extension method:

```
public static string ToRatingImageLink(this decimal value)
    {
        string imageLinkFormat = "http://somewhere.com/images/rating_{0}.gif";
        return string.Format(imageLinkFormat, value.ToString().Replace(".0", string.Empty).Replace(".", string.Empty);
    }
```

Guess it was a case of "KISS" and "DRY". In this case the syntactic sugar of extension methods kept it DRY, and and the actual one-line implementation satisfies KISS.

Comment: I tried creating a `NumberFormatInfo`, but I get `Decimal separator cannot be the empty string`. Shame.

Comment: +1 for asking well structured question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Decimal delimiter depends on current culture preferences:

```
d.Replace(
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator,
    String.Empty)
```

will replace `'.'` or `','` with `""`

Comment: It's probably easier to use a CultureInfo when converting the number to string, as suggested by other answers. Then you *know* the string format, and can simply replace the dot.

Comment: @Kobi: Yes, when you know and absolutely sure that delimiter is dot not comma. Dynamic delimiter is very easy to use, minimizes strings hardcoding and very intelligent as OP asked

Answer (score 4):

If you could live with strings like `00, 05, 10, 15, 20 ...` etc., you could simply use

```
(rating * 10).ToString("00")
```

If not, use `InvariantCulture` as argument to `ToString` in order to force the use of a decimal point (".") in all countries (in Germany the default would be "," for example):

```
rating.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Replace(".","");
```

Comment: `Replace(".", "")` does seem like the best way.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use the "cheekily" method you describe at the end. In pure semantics of the thing, you're manipulating a string, not the actual number, so I think a string replacement would be exactly the correct prescription here.

If you really want to overcomplicate it, consider creating a new [IFormatProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx) for this situation. This would be a better way of catching potential errors, but it adds a layer of complexity.

Answer (score 2):

you can just use `Replace(".", string.Empty);` with no need for `Replace(".0", string.Empty)`

check the below code

```
double[] x = { 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5 };
            foreach (var item in x)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(item.ToString().Replace(".", string.Empty));
            }
```

the result will be 
[image]

Comment: +1 for taking the time to try out your answer and showing the proof of it working.

Answer (score 1):

Use a hashtable/dictionary and keep mappings from double to string in there. That will be much more robust and simpler than parsing your double

Comment: What's the difference between that and a hard coded switch/if else statement? Only difference is being able to do a lookup, but the actual code which still need to be hard coded (ie items.Add(0.5, "05"))

Comment: A hashtable could potentially increase performance if you're dealing with larger lookup tables, but for as small a list as your example you'd be better off with a giant switch statement.

Comment: True, and if there is a direct simple way to do it, then sure we should not use a dictionary. However if I had to parse and put some string manipulation logic then i would avoid that simply because that is error prone.

Comment: A dictionary is overkill.  You could do this with an array.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid messing with decimal formats, I would format the whole part as an integer and use an array lookup for the fractional part:

```
public static string ToRatingImageLink(this decimal value)
{
    string imageLinkFormat = "http://somewhere.com/images/rating_{0}{1}.gif";
    int index = decimal.ToInt32(decimal.Round(value * 2));
    return string.Format(imageLinkFormat, index / 2, Suffix[index % 2]);
}

static readonly string[] Suffix = { "", "5" };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call `ToString()`, and then use a regular expression like replacing
`"([0-9])\\.([0-9])" with "\\1\\2"`,
which, although still a bit of a hack, would be less fragile than `Replace(".","")`

Comment: This seems like a lot of overhead if he controls both ends of the conversion, which it appears like he does.

Comment: As i said in the question, i can be sure of the format of the double, as there is an existing extension method which rounds to the nearest half. I was hoping for a secondary extension method which returns the string. ie double.RoundToNearestHalf().ToImageLink().

Comment: As much as I like regular expressions (and I do), .net can handle it better. Still, something like `Regex.Replace("1.5", @"\D", "")` is probably more robust, your regex makes specific assumptions as to the format of the string.

Answer (score -1):

Don't try to find a simpler answer to something that's already simple. The easiest way to do it is to use this code:

```
double dblNumber = 1.5;
string strDouble = dblNumber.ToString("N1").Replace(".","").Trim('0');
```

If it is something you are going to be doing a lot, wrap it in a function:

```
string ConvertToString(double dblNumber)
{
    return dblNumber.ToString("N1").Replace(".","").Trim('0');
}
```

Comment: I thought about `TrimEnd`, but keep in mind it turns `0` to `""`. `Trim` also turns `05` to `5`, which is wrong.